# Use Javascript to generate Rails Text Array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to write some JavaScript that allows a user to enter a zip code one at a time and build up an array that will be submitted to a Rails app.

Here are the relevant pieces:

**Controller.rb - Params**

```
    {:zipcodes => []}
```

**Schema.rb**

```
    t.text     "zipcodes",       default: [],              array: true
```

**html.erb** *The javascript updates the value of a hidden element*

```
    <%= f.hidden_field :zipcodes, id:"zipcodes-hidden-tag", name:"provider[zipcodes]" %>
```

**js.erb file**

```
    //Adding a zipcode
     var array = []; 
     $("#addZipcode").click(

    function addZipcode() {

        x = $("#newZipcode").val();  // gets the zipcode entered by the user
        array.push(x);
        $("#zipcode_div").text(array);  // updates a div so the user can see the data entered
        $("#newZipcode").val("");  //clear the zipcode box after submitting
        $("#zipcodes-hidden-tag").val("[" + '"",' + '"' + array.join('","') + '"' + "]");  //puts the brackets, empty quote block, and quotes around the elements and updates the hidden field value
    }); //Adding a zipcode
```

This is how it looks in the Rails console when it is successful (using a multi-select field):

```
    "provider"=>{"zipcodes"=>["", "90210", "90211", "90212"],
```

When using the Javascript generated array, I can see the following value getting passed to Rails which is the correct formatting

```
    ["","90210","90211","90212"]
```

But in the Rails console, it's coming through like this:

```
   "provider"=>{"zipcodes"=>"[\"\",\"90210\",\"90211\",\"90212\"]"
```

And Rails is stating

```
    Unpermitted parameter: zipcodes
```

I feel like there are two problems at play here.  An extra set of quotes are getting added to the beginning and end of the brackets:

```
    "[  ...   ]"
```

And the double quotes are getting converted into literals with the back slashes.

Any thoughts on what I need to change to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from the console,

```
"provider"=>{"zipcodes"=>"[\"\",\"90210\",\"90211\",\"90212\"]"
```

is exactly what you should expect. Your javascript code encodes the array as a string and submits it through a hidden field, so `params[:provider][:zipcodes]` is a string in your controller. In order to assign it to your model, you'll need to do something like

```
provider.zipcodes = JSON.parse(params[:provider][:zipcodes])
```

The `Unpermitted parameter: zipcodes` message is most likely because you are mass-assigning to your model without whitelisting or removing the `zipcodes` key from your params hash.

**Edit:**

To get around the strong parameters, try deleting the `zipcodes` key.

```
provider.zipcodes = JSON.parse(params[:provider].delete(:zipcodes))

safe_params = params.require(:provider).permit(:any, :other, :fields)
provider.update!(safe_params)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing.  I still get the 'Unpermitted parameter: zipcodes' in the console but it's saving to the DB.  I changed the permit entry to just ':zipcodes' and removed it completely but all 3 have the same result.  I'm not sure what's going on there at the moment.

Comment: I added this line to the controller:  `@provider.zipcodes = JSON.parse(params[:provider].delete(:zipcodes))` in both the Create and Update methods and removed `:zipcodes` from the params list.  The error went away on the Update but still says `Unpermitted parameter: zipcodes` during the Create action.  The values are still saving to the DB though so I'm not going to worry about this too much now.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line:

```
$("#zipcodes-hidden-tag").val("[" + '"",' + '"' + array.join('","') + '"' + "]");
```

if you change it to:

```
$("#zipcodes-hidden-tag").val('"' + array.join('","'));
```

then you will have values as: `"979794,297942,24444"`

Which would make it super easy to convert into an array in your controller:

```
params[:provider][:zipcodes].split(',') 
#=> ["979794", "297942", "24444"]
```

Which can be:

```
params[:provider][:zipcodes] = params[:provider][:zipcodes].split(',')
```